# How to change button value once all required field is filled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I'm trying to change the value of the submit button, only after required fields are filled. but as per my below code the value is changing even the required fields are not filled, additionally I'm need advice on how to mark at least one checkbox field as required.

```js
$('#formSubmit').click(function(){
  $(this).val("Processing");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label>Call Me
    <input type="checkbox" name="contactMethod[]" id="contactMethod[]" value="CAll Me">
  </label>
  <br />
  <label>Email Me
    <input type="checkbox" name="contactMethod[]" id="contactMethod[]" value="Email Me">
  </label>
  <br />
  <hr />
  <input type="text" id="formName" name="formName" placeholder="Please Enter Your Name" required>
  <br />
  <input type="email" id="formEmail" name="formEmail" placeholder="Please Enter Your Email Address" required>
  <br />
  <input type="text" id="formMobile" name="formMobile" placeholder="Please Enter Your Contact No" min="10" max="10" required>
  <br />
  <input type="submit" id="formSubmit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen to `submit` event instead:

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#myForm').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#formSubmit').val("Processing");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <form id="myForm">

        <label>Call Me
            <input type="checkbox" name="contactMethod[]" id="contactMethod[]" value="CAll Me">
        </label>
        <br />
        <label>Email Me
            <input type="checkbox" name="contactMethod[]" id="contactMethod[]" value="Email Me">
        </label>
        <br />
        <hr />
        <input type="text" id="formName" name="formName" placeholder="Please Enter Your Name" required>
        <br />
        <input type="email" id="formEmail" name="formEmail" placeholder="Please Enter Your Email Address" required>
        <br />
        <input type="text" id="formMobile" name="formMobile" placeholder="Please Enter Your Contact No" min="10" max="10" required>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" id="formSubmit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: What about **change the value of the submit button, only after required fields are filled**?

Comment: What I understand after reading his post and his code is that he wants to change the button text after submitting but just when form is correctly fullfilled. Not that he wants to change the text in the moment that fields are filled, so this will work.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    function validateForm() {
      var isValid = true;
      $('input[required]').each(function() {
      if ( $(this).val() === '' ){
        isValid = false;
      }
  });
  return isValid;
}

$('#formSubmit').click(function(){
    if(validateForm()) {
      $(this).val("Processing");

    }
            
});

   
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<form>

<label>Call Me
<input type="checkbox" name="contactMethod[]" id="contactMethod[]" value="CAll Me">
</label>
<br />
<label>Email Me
<input type="checkbox" name="contactMethod[]" id="contactMethod[]" value="Email Me">
</label>
<br />
<hr />
<input type="text" id="formName" name="formName" placeholder="Please Enter Your Name" required>
<br />
<input type="email" id="formEmail" name="formEmail" placeholder="Please Enter Your Email Address" required>
<br />
<input type="text" id="formMobile" name="formMobile" placeholder="Please Enter Your Contact No" min="10" max="10" required>
<br />
<input type="submit" id="formSubmit" value="Submit" />
</form>


</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding my solution since nobody seems to answer the second part of the question. You need to modify your markup a little as done below in the answer.

```js
function makeChecks() {
  checkBoxes = $("input:checked"); //Find checked checkboxes
  if (checkBoxes.length) { //Only submit if some checked checkbox(es) exist
    $('#exampleForm').find('input').each(function() {
      if ($(this).prop('required') && $(this).val() !== "") {
        $("#formSubmit").val("Processing");
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="exampleForm">
    <label>Call Me
            <input type="checkbox" name="contactMethod[]" 
            id="contactMethod[]" value="CAll Me">
        </label>
    <br />
    <label>Email Me
            <input type="checkbox" name="contactMethod[]" 
            id="contactMethod[]" value="Email Me">
        </label>
    <br />
    <hr />
    <input type="text" id="formName" name="formName" placeholder="Please Enter Your Name" required>
    <br />
    <input type="email" id="formEmail" name="formEmail" placeholder="Please Enter Your Email Address" required>
    <br />
    <input type="text" id="formMobile" name="formMobile" placeholder="Please Enter Your Contact No" min="10" max="10" required>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" id="formSubmit" onclick="makeChecks()" value="Submit" />
  </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Id must be unique. Unique id must be assigned to each checkbox. Add required attribute to the checkbox controls.

```
  <label>Call Me
   <input type="checkbox" name="contactMethod[]" id="callMe" value="CAll Me" required>
  </label>
  <br />
  <label>Email Me
   <input type="checkbox" name="contactMethod[]" id="emailMe" value="Email Me" required>
  </label>
```

You can use `$(elem).val() != ''` to check if a input element has been entered.

For checkbox, you can use `$(elem).prop('checked')` to check if a checkbox has been checked.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
 $('#formSubmit').click(function(e){
  if((!$('#callMe').prop('checked') || !$('#emailMe').prop('checked')) && $('#formName').val() != '' && $('#formEmail').val() != '' && $('#formMobile').val() != '')
  $(this).val("Processing");
 });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/snehansh/nwh0vct8/3/